# How to make a struct link list inside of a struct vector

Tags: c++, stl

I've created these two structs below. I basically want to be able to append a list of `destInfo` to a vector of `node`.

```
enum status{
    connected, lost };

enum association{
    neighbor, notNeighbor };

struct destInfo{
    destInfo(association type, status health, int destID, int nh, int cost, double pTime):
    type(type), health(health), destID(destID), nh(nh), cost(cost), pTime(pTime){}
    association type;
    status health;
    int destID;
    int nh;
    int cost;
    double pTime;
};


struct node{
    node(int id, int size):id(id), size(size){}
    int id;
    int size;
    std::list <destInfo> dest;
};
```

However, I'm having a real hard time actually figuring out how to access the list inside of the vector.

```
std::vector <node> router;
node p(0, 0);
router.push_back(p);

destInfo info(neighbor, connected, 4,3,2,.123);
router.at(0).dest.push_back(info);
std::cout << router.at(0).dest->nh <<std::endl;
```

My understanding is that when trying to access `dest` from `router` that it should already be a pointer type and to access the content inside of `dest` I would have to dereference the pointer, but I keep on getting the error `base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type`

Comment: One item was added with push_back and the index for that item would be 0 while you try to access non-existing item at index 3. That is about C arrays indexing. Much before C++. Maybe you should start with real basics as plain C?

Comment: ooops. That was suppose to be at index 0. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: `dest` is not a pointer. Oh, that's what the error message says!

Comment: Anyway, you can use `std::list` of values, *or*  a do-it-yourself linked list of nodes with values, but ordinarily there's no point in a `std::list` of nodes with values, and absolutely no point in a node with a value and a `std::list`.

Comment: Yeah, I think I might just go ahead and make my own linked list then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
std::vector <node> router;
node p(0, 0);
router.push_back(p);

destInfo info(neighbor, connected, 4,3,2,.123);
router.at(0).dest.push_back(info);
std::cout << router.at(0).dest.front().nh <<std::endl;
```

Basically, you are storing a vector of node objects and each node has a list "object" and "not a pointer" to an std::list. So, when you say "router.at(0).dest", you are actually referring to the list of destinfo and not a pointer to the list of destinfo. Hence you are getting the error "base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type".  Either you would have to loop through the list and access the nh field.

The code above uses the STL list.front() method which returns a reference to the first object in the list.

Comment: Ahh, okay, that makes sense! If that's the case though, what would be the difference between calling `router.at(0).dest.front().nh` vs `router.at(0).dest.nh`? Wouldn't that second one still be accessing the `object lists nh`?

Comment: router.at(0).dest is a list object. The nh member is within the destinfo structure which is within the list. The list class does not have any member called nh. So it would throw a compiler error. But router.at(0).dest.front() returns a reference to the destinfo struct within the list object and hence router.at(0).dest.front().nh is valid.